# Google tests don't show report messages

Tags: c++, googletest

Google test EXPECT and ASSERT macros don't show output text, that i try out with << operator

Project builds using CMake with MSVC compiler.

```
TEST(bar, foo)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1) << "Some text";
}
```

I expect somo output in console. But it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context `operator <<` can be used to provide a custom failure message. Since 1 equals to 1 no failure happens and nothing is printed.

Comment: Thanks, i don't thik about this